# Deep copying closures in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have a function that cycles between an array of functions, calling them in order with the passed arguments in sequence infinitely.

```
public extension Array {
    /// Cycles the elements in `self` infinitely.
    /// - warning: Do not call on an empty array.
    public func cycle() -> UnfoldSequence<Element, Int> {
        let count = self.count
        return sequence(state: 0, next: { (index: inout Int) in
            let x = self[index]
            index = (index + 1) % count
            return x
        })
    }
}

func cycle(funcs: [(((Int, Int)) -> (Int, Int))]) -> (((Int, Int)) -> (Int, Int)) {
    var cycled = funcs.cycle()
    return  { (coords) in
        let current = cycled.next()!
        return current(coords)
    }
}
```

So if I have these two functions for example:

```
func leftPattern(tuple:(x: Int, y: Int)) -> (Int, Int) {
    return (tuple.x, tuple.y - 1)
}

func upPattern(tuple:(x: Int, y: Int)) -> (Int, Int) {
    return (tuple.x - 1, tuple.y)
}
```

I can cycle between them infinitely:

```
let leftUp = cycle(funcs: [leftPattern, upPattern])
```

leftUp would be equal to...

```
[leftPattern, upPattern, leftPattern, upPattern, ...]
```

Trouble is, I need a way to restart this sequence, because as I pass this function around, it starts at the wrong part of the sequence.

Since functions are passed by reference, the solution I thought of would be to somehow deep copy my generated function for example:

```
let leftUp2 = copy(leftUp)
leftUp(...) // would use leftPattern for example
leftUp2(...) // would ALSO use leftPattern, not affected by calling leftUp before
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Offtopic ‘// - warning: Do not call on an empty array.’ you could remove that and just throw a fatalerror if the count equals zero

Comment: @J.Doe thanks, didn't know about that, I got that code from  [here](http://rosslebeau.com/2016/swift-infinite-lists)

Comment: What do you hope to achieve with the `cycle` function, instead of just passing around the unfold sequence directly?

Comment: Well, I have a function that takes a function of type `((Int, Int)) -> ((Int, Int))`. Cycle just combines many of those sequences into one function with the same signature.